# Extract data from non column file (in awk)

Tags: python, perl, apache-flex, awk, grep

I am trying to extract some specific values from a non column files. The files have the format

```
 16O     ADOPTED LEVELS, GAMMAS        1993TI07                  93NP     199902
 16O   L 0.0          0+               STABLE                                   
 16O 2 L ISPIN=0                                                                
 16O 3 L XREF=ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQ                                                  
 16O   L 6049.4    10  0+              67 PS     5                              
 16O 2 L ISPIN=0                                                                
 16O 3 L XREF=ABCEFIJKMP                                                        
 16O   G 6048.2    10          [E0]                             100             
 16O   L 6129.89   4   3-              18.4 PS   5                              
 16O 2 L ISPIN=0$ MOMM1=+1.668 12 (1989RA17)                                    
 16O 3 L XREF=ABCEFHIJKLNOPQ                                                    
 16O   G 6128.63   4  100      [E3]                                             
 16O 2 G BE3W=13.5 7
```

I am interested in the values after the sequence `16O   L`. For instanse *0.0, 6049.4, 6129.89* etc. In general the values that I want to extract from those files are after the sequence `(Number)(Element)(spaces)L(space)`.

The tricky thing is that if the `(Element)` consists of one letter there are 3 spaces. if the `(Element)` consists of two letters there are 2 spaces. An example file is

```
 10BE    ADOPTED LEVELS, GAMMAS        2004TI06                  04NP     200705
 10BE  L 0.0         0+                1.51E+6 Y 4                              
 10BE2 L ISPIN=1 $ %B-=100                                                      
 10BE3 L XREF=ABDEFIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZabceghij                                    
 10BE cL T         from weighted average of T{-1/2}=1.51 Ma 6 (Hofmann et al.,  
 10BE2cL Nucl. Instrum. Meth. Phys. Res. |b 24-25 (1987) 276),                  
 10BE3cL T{-1/2}=1.53 Ma 5% (1993Mi26), and T{-1/2}=1.48 Ma 5% (1993Mi26).      
 10BE  L 3368.03   3 2+                125 FS    12                             
 10BE2 L ISPIN=1 $ %IT=100                                                      
 10BE3 L XREF=ABCDEFIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabceghij                                  
 10BE cL           B(E2)=52 e{+2} fm{+4} 6 (1987Ra01).                          
 10BE cL E         from {+9}Be(n,|g) (1983Ke11). Other value: 3368.34 keV {I43} 
 10BE2cL (1999Bu26).                                                            
 10BE2 L WIDTHG=3.66E-3 EV 35                                                   
 10BE  G 3367.415  30 100      E2                                               
 10BE2 G WIDTHG=3.66E-3 EV 35$BE2W=8.00 76                                      
 10BE  L 5958.39   5 2+                55 FS     LT                             
 10BE2 L ISPIN=1 $ %IT=100                                                      
 10BE3 L XREF=DFJKLMPRTUWYbeghi                                                 
 10BE cL E         from {+9}Be(n,|g) (1983Ke11). Other value: 5958.3 keV {I3}   
 10BE2cL (1969Al17).                                                            
 10BE  G 2589.999  60 90     GTM1                                               
 10BE  G 5955.9     5 10     LTE2                                               
 10BE  L 13.05E3   10                  290 KEV   130                        A   
 10BE2 L %A GT 0                                                                
 10BE3 L XREF=E                                                                 
 10BE cL E         |G: from {+7}Li({+7}Li,|a+{+6}He) (2001Cu06).
```

Is there a way to get those values using `awk`?
Is there another language for these kinds of jobs?

I used

```
awk '/   L/ { print $3 } ' file
```

for the first filetype(i.e. {3spaces}L) and it works. I used

```
awk '/  L/ { print $3 } ' file
```

for the second filetype(i.e. {2spaces}L) and it gives weird results(i.e. it prints values after the sequence `(two spaces)G` and I cannot understand why. The only way it can work is to use

```
awk '/  L / { print $3 } ' file
```

(i.e. one extra space after L). Why is this happening for the second filetype?
Is there a way to use one code for both filetypes?

Comment: Might be even easier using `grep`.

Comment: @devnull: `grep`? I've never heard of it! I'll search it!!!

Comment: tl;dr. post a shorter example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the value present in the line "160   L" If thats the case this should do the job

```
awk '/16O   L/ { print $3 } ' filename
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! It really works! is there a way to make it more automated for every file in that format? Every file has the sequence `(Number)(Element)(3spaces)L(space)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '/[0-9]+[A-Z] {3}L / { print $3 } ' file
```

or

```
awk '$1~/[0-9]+[A-Z]/&&$2=="L"{print $3}' file
```

Using grep

```
grep -iPo '\d+[A-Z] {3}L \K[\d.]*' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The 1st code line doesn't work. The 2nd and 3rd are working like a charm! Playing a bit I used `awk '/   L/ { print $3 } ' file` and it worked. What's the difference between your code and mine? I suppose there must be a reason for writing `[0-9]+[A-Z] {3}` but I don't know why...

Comment: You need thank with vote it up. :-) I did the test in GNU awk v4.1, can you confirm your awk version by this command: ` awk --version|head -1`

Comment: In Solaris, please run /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Comment: I am not running Solaris. I am running Linux. Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

when I saw this question, I thought it would be an easy grep line, I was wrong!! I test at least 10 times with my grep line, it didn't work! finally I found out why. 
"sh*t!"

the data in your example:

```
16O ....
```

I was thinking they were :

```
160 ....
```

see the difference?  :(

ok, here is the line:

```
grep -Po '^16O {3}L \K[\d.]*' file
```

it outputs:

```
0.0
6049.4
6129.89
6917.1
7116.85
8871.9
9585
9844.5
10356
10957
11080
11096.7
11260
11520
11600
12049
12440
12530
....
```

if you want it to be in your "general" way:

```
grep -Po '^\d\d[A-Z] {3}L \K[\d.]*'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! Sorry for the inconvenience about the `0` VS `O`. I should've mentioned it! I've never heard of `grep`! It seems quite powerful!!! The thing is that I used `grep -Po '^16O {3}L \K[\d.]*' 16O.ensdf` with `16O.ensdf` being the input file but I get nothing. Note that terminal is open in the directory where the `.ensdf` file is.

Comment: what is the output of `grep --version` @Thanos

Comment: It's `grep (GNU grep) 2.10
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.`